# jeditable callback has empty values

Tags: jquery, jeditable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jeditable callback has empty values //OR// How to display edited text after clicking save button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734124/jeditable-callback-has-empty-values-or-how-to-display-edited-text-after-clic)

In my code I found value and settings are empty in callback function...

can anyone help why is that so?

```
$(".edit_area").editable('/cgi-bin/mycgiscript.cgi', {
event       : 'dblclick',       //or dblclick
type        : 'textarea',
rows        : 2,
cols        : 30,
cancel      : 'Cancel',
submit      : 'Save',
indicator   : '<img src="images/indicator.gif">',
placeholder : 'Double Click to enter text',
tooltip     : 'Double Click to edit...',
name        : 'name',
id      : 'id',
callback    : function(value, settings) {
console.log('value='+value);
console.log('settings='+settings);
console.log('callback executed='+value);
return(value);
}
});
```

I used callback, because after 'SAVE'ing the edited text. The edited text is not displayed on the HTML page. It is properly being saved in the backend database. I have re run the ajax call which displays the updated information from the backend server...

editable is attached to the div in the html table which is being generated from an ajax call. if it helps...